# MSRP value incorrect for simple products with custom options

Tags: configurable-product, price, ce-1.9.0.1, simple-product

can someone help me figure this out

I've modified catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml as per:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/261633/P15/

```
<?php $_price = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getMsrp()) ?>
<?php if ($_product->getMsrp()): ?>
    <?php $_msrpPrice = $this->helper('core')->currency($_product->getMsrp(),true,true) ?>
    <p class="special-price">
    <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Manufacturer\'s Suggested Retail Price'); ?></span>
    <span class="old-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_product->getId() ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"><?php echo $_msrpPrice ?></span>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This adds the MSRP into the product page as expected, however for some products the value being shown is not the same as the one entered into the attribute in the backend:

- It looks like Configurable products have the correct value until an option is selected, then MSRP changes to be the Price.
- Some Simple products with custom options are showing price as MSRP and also adding the cost of the custom options when selected.
- Other Simple products with custom options are working fine.
- Simple products with no options are showing the correct MSRP.

All products are showing the MSRP correctly in Category pages.

I'm completely stumped, any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that something changed into magento 1.7 onwards
So I figured out what’s to do to get Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price shown.

```
<?php echo $this->__('Manufacturer\'s Suggested Retail Price: '); ?>
<?php echo substr($_product->getMsrp(),0,-2);></span>
```

that’s it

Or refer to: http://sarfarazlaghari.wordpress.com/2014/11/13/magento-msrp-value-incorrect-for-configurable-product/

Comment: even though the link could provide the answer it is not normally recommended to answer with simply a link. could you summarize the content of the link for us here.

Comment: I hope now its worth..